# Why is the controller I created not working?

Tags: controller, magento2

I tried to create my controller, but it doesn't work.
Controller:

```
<?php

namespace AlanStorm\HelloWorld\Controller\Hello;

use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;

class World implements ActionInterface
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="AlanStorm_HelloWorld">
    </module>
</config>
```

routes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="hello_world" frontName="hello_world">
            <module name="AlanStorm_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
```

registration.php:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'AlanStorm_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yELvE.png)

structure of module files:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqrkL.png)

P.S. I tried to run magento setup:di:compile, magento c:f, magento c:c but it didn't help
P.P.S in config.php the module is enabled

Comment: Hey, your `routes.xml` file does not close the <config> tag. Therefore the router is unable to route to your controller class.

Comment: it is there, it just wasn't copied here. the problem is something else

Comment: Then you probably put `routes.xml` into the `etc/` folder, but for the frontend you have to put it into `etc/frontend/`.

Comment: no
there is a file structure on the attached photo. there you can see that the file roures.xml is located in etc/frontend

Comment: That's wierd, it works for me flawlessly with your files. Did you run the typical deployment commands? Magento does require those to apply changes.
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `php bin/magento cache:flush` should suffice

Comment: these commands didin't help. It's still doesn't work

Comment: Does AlanStorm_HelloWorld get listed when you run `php bin/magento module:status` ? If yes, under active modules?

Comment: Yes, this module is enabled
Also I tried to create the same controller in project without ScandiPWA and it works. But I want to understand why it doesn't work in ScandiPWA project